# How do I save the focus context and return to it in an OSX application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, focus, menubar

I'm writing a menubar application that shows a window when a global hotkey is pressed. The application has no dock icon and no normal menu (just the statusItem).

Prior to activating the application, lets say I have a text box on a webpage in chrome focused. How can I refocus that text box when my application is dismissed.

If you're familiar with Text Expander, they do something similar.

Comment: I always thought that a simple `-orderOut` was pretty good about returning focus; but this is a great question. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. You need an NSRunningApplication:

`@implementation AppDelegate {
    NSRunningApplication *_previousApplication;
}`

Then store the previous application before you become active:

`_previousApplication = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];`

Finally, after you deactivate, just bring back the other application:

`[_previousApplication activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];`